# Tool for drawing SLD trees in Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, sld-resolution

Just as an example, I have the following SWI-Prolog Program (inverts a list):

```
inverte(L,LI) :- 
   inverte(L,[],LI).

inverte([], Aux, Aux).
inverte([P | R], Aux, LI) :- 
   inverte(R, [P | Aux], LI).
```

Are there any tools for Ubuntu 20.04 in order to view the SLD tree?
Like the following one, that solves the query:
`inverte([a,b,c], X).`
[image]

Comment: @GuyCoder Thanks. I had already seen that SWI package, however, it is necessary to convert to LaTeX and I am looking for a one-click solution.

Comment: @GuyCoder I also think that both packages you presented do not show unification on each step of the tree. Not sure.

Comment: @GuyCoder Thank you very much. I am going to register to Discourse forum.